# Add links to taxonomy links area

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have to add a few links to where the taxonomy terms are displaying, I am using a custom module. I tried hook_link but it add links at the end of the node, How can I add links to the right side of the node title

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend Scott's answer:

you can still use your custom module with `hook_link()`, but you need to edit `node.tpl.php` or `node-type.tpl.php`.

i.e. the Garland `node.tpl.php` looks like:

```
<?php
// $Id: node.tpl.php,v 1.5 2007/10/11 09:51:29 goba Exp $
?>
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="node<?php if ($sticky) { print ' sticky'; } ?><?php if (!$status) { print ' node-unpublished'; } ?>">

<?php print $picture ?>

<?php if ($page == 0): ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($submitted): ?>
    <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted; ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content clear-block">
    <?php print $content ?>
  </div>

  <div class="clear-block">
    <div class="meta">
    <?php if ($taxonomy): ?>
      <div class="terms"><?php print $terms ?></div>
    <?php endif;?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($links): ?>
      <div class="links"><?php print $links; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

what you need to do is move the `<?php if ($links): ...` block somewhere before `<?php if ($submitted): ...`

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="node<?php if ($sticky) { print ' sticky'; } ?><?php if (!$status) { print ' node-unpublished'; } ?>">

<?php print $picture ?>

<?php if ($page == 0): ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($links): ?>
    <div class="links"><?php print $links; ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($submitted): ?>
    <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted; ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>
...
```

then float both the title and the links block, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you could theme nodes yourself (i.e., create your own `node.tpl.php` or 'node-*type*.tpl.php') and add whatever you want after the $terms variable (or anywhere).